# PCs on domain can not resolve external IP addresses using the DC's DNS Server

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, dhcp

I currently have a domain controller which handles all DHCP and DNS. The DHCP works just fine and the domain controller itself can use the internet with no issues. However, PCs that are part of the domain are not able to use external websites, only internal.

Does anyone have any way I can solve this issue? Thank you

Server: Windows Server 2008 R2
PC: Win7 Enterprise x64

Edit: (domain controller)

```
C:\Users\bcollyer>nslookup google.com
Server:  localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:4009:809::100e
          173.194.41.166
          173.194.41.165
          173.194.41.169
          173.194.41.162
          173.194.41.161
          173.194.41.160
          173.194.41.168
          173.194.41.167
          173.194.41.164
          173.194.41.163
          173.194.41.174
```

Edit 2: Domain PC

```
C:\Users\bcollyer>netstat -rn
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...30 85 a9 f7 8a 21 ......Atheros AR8161/8165 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Control
ler (NDIS 6.20)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.16.0.67     172.16.0.202     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       172.16.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      172.16.0.202    276
     172.16.0.202  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.0.202    276
   172.16.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.0.202    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.16.0.202    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.0.202    276
===========================================================================

Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================

Persistent Routes:
  None
```

BTW I have no javascript on the server so can't reply to individual answers... Sorry!

Comment: Is that lookup from the DC or a domain PC?  Please can you [edit] and add the results of a `netstat -rn` from a domain PC?

Comment: Could you add the `nslookup google.com` from the domain PC as well?  It all looks right so far.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the server isn't using 127.0.0.1 / it's local ip as the DNS server, whilst other machines are working fine.

Anyway, a basic test to do:

From the dns server, type:

`nslookup google.com` and see what it says under `default server`.

Anyway, in the DNS server management console, make sure that either the root servers are turned on, or you have it set to forward queries to your ISP/favourite DNS provider.